# Ideias para uma questão envolvendo html e css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um app onde os usuários poderão enviar fotos que funciona da seguinte maneira:

**O app**

Quando um usuário escolhe várias fotos, através de um loop, é gerado um formulário para cada foto para que seja preenchido o título e descrição.

**O código**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-3"><span class="preview">Um preview da imagem enviada aqui</div></div>
 <div class="col-md-12>Aqui irá o formulário referente a foto</div>
</div>
<div class="form">
</div>
```

O código acima é gerado através de javascript e DEVE ficar entre a div `container`.

Fiz um pequeno CSS para que, quando alguem clicar no preview da imagem, o formulário correspondente a ela apareça:

```
$('body').on('click', '.preview', function(){
    $('.hideform').hide();
    var data = $(this).attr('data-ref');
    myDiv = $('div[data-ref="' + data + '"]');
    myDiv.appendTo('.form).show();
});
```

**O problema**

O problema consiste no que disse acima. Estou usando um `appendTo` para que quando o usuário clique no preview, ele jogue o formulário em outra div para que fique bonito.

**Mas eu não posso tirar o fomulário de dentro da div `container` devido uma limitação do app na hora do envio.**

Mas se eu não usar o `appendTo` a visualização fica horrível devido ao formulário aparecer logo após cada imagem jogando todo o resto para baixo.
Eu gostaria que visualização aparecesse da seguinte maneira sem ter que tirá-la do `container` (usando o appendTo ela sai e ocorre o erro acima):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como ela aparecesse se eu retirar o `appendTo` e o app funciona corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem uma ideia de solução para que meu form apareça dessa maneira sem eu precisa remove-lo do `container`?

Comment: Tem um bug no seu HTML, você abre um span e fecha ele como /div...

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um erro na estrutura do HTML.

Comment: Repare que falta um `'` aqui na classe do `form`: `myDiv.appendTo('.form).show();`